# Antlr evaluation order

Tags: sequence, antlr, antlr4, grammar, evaluation

I defined the following expression rule using Antlr 4 for a script language,

basically I am trying to evaluate

x = y.z.aa * 6

the correct evaluation order should be y.z then y.z.aa then it times 6; 
((y.z).aa) * 6

however after the parsing aa*6 evaluated first, then z.(aa*6) then y.(z.(aa*6)), it becomes
y.(z.(aa * 6))

the square bracket is evaluated right
x = y[z][aa] * 6

can anyone help to point what I did wrong in dot access rule?

```
expression
:   primary                             #PrimaryExpression
|   expression ('.' expression ) +      #DotAccessExpression
|   expression ('[' expression ']')+    #ArrayAccessExpression
|   expression ('*'|'/') expression     #MulExpression
|   expression ('+'|'-') expression     #AddExpression   
;

primary
:   '(' expression ')'
|   literal   
|   ident
;

literal
:   NUMBER        
|   STRING
|   NULL
|   TRUE
|   FALSE            
;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You used the following rule:

```
expression ('.' expression)+
```

This rule does not fit the syntax pattern for a *binary* expression, so it's actually getting treated as a *suffix* expression. In particular, the `expression` following a `.` character is no longer restricted within the precedence hierarchy. You *may* be additionally affected by [issue #679](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/679), but the real resolution is the same either way. You need to replace this alternative with the following:

```
expression '.' expression
```

The same goes for the `ArrayAccessExpression`, which should be written as follows:

```
expression '[' expression ']' #ArrayAccessExpression
```

Comment: Sam, thanks much for the explanation and fix, it works great. You and Bart are antlr angels on stackoverflow.